# Odoo getting selected value in selection field

Tags: python, odoo

May I ask how it is possible to get the current selected value in a selection field.

Now I am working in the     sale.order.line model.
There is a state field which is a selection field.
I want to check if it is defined and is in state sale.

I tried to use
`if (state='sale')`
`if (state.name='sale')`
`if (state.type='sale')`

They all end up as a syntax error.

Comment: if your function in sale order line use order_id.state=="sale"
inside if you will need "=="

Comment: You can use the `line` record reference to access the `state` field value, for example: `if line.state == 'sale'`: